# Stripe product image does not display after upload

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, next.js, stripe-payments

The image for the Stripe products I upload via code does not display, it looks like it attempts to load the image (as there is a loading effect that occurs), but then the image does not display. I am using Firebase Firestore (FF) and Firebase Storage (FS) to save the product and image, I then get the downloadURL from FS and this is passed to Stripe in the images array. All other information uploaded to Stripe (i.e. price, product name) displays correctly in the Stripe dashboard. I have contacted Stripe support and they have stated that the most likely scenario is that FS is not allowing access to image. I have altered my security rules in FS to allow all reads, so I cannot understand why Stripe is unable to access the image.

First I uploaded the image via a FileReader and data_url, but I thought that may be causing the issue and switched to just uploading the .png file without running it through the FileReader.

The code:
**\admin\shop\page.tsx**

```
...
const addImage = (e) => {
        setSelectedFile(e.target.files[0]);
};

const createProduct = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const productData = { // Dummy test data
            id: prodId,
            heading: 'Apple',
            subheading: 'Apples are very healthy',
            text: 'This is a new product being added to firestore',
            price: '499',
        };

        const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, 'products'), productData);

        const imageRef = ref(storage, `products/${docRef.id}/image`);

        if (selectedFile) {         
            await uploadBytes(imageRef, selectedFile).then(async () => {
                const downloadURL = await getDownloadURL(imageRef);
                await updateDoc(doc(db, 'products', docRef.id), {
                    imageUrl: downloadURL,
                });
            });
        }

        const downloadURLCreated = await getDownloadURL(imageRef);

        const productCreate = await axios.post(
            '/api/createProduct',
            {
                prodData: productData,
                prodId: docRef.id,
                prodImgUrl: downloadURLCreated,
            },
            {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    Accept: 'image/png',
                },
            }
        );
};
```

**/api/createProduct/route.tsx**

```
export async function POST(request) {
    const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY, { apiVersion: '2022-11-15' });

    let data = await request.json();

    const { prodData, prodId, prodImgUrl } = data;

    const product = await stripe.products.create({
        id: `${prodId}`,
        active: true,
        name: `${prodData.heading}`,
        description: `${prodData.subheading}`,
        default_price_data: {
            currency: 'gbp',
            unit_amount_decimal: `${prodData.price}`,
        },
        images: [`${prodImgUrl}`],
    });

    return NextResponse.json(data);
}
```

I get a status 200 response from Stripe, with the correct url to the FS image contained within. As stated, Stripe believe that I am making the request in the correct manner, so it must be something to do with FS access? I am stumped and considering using something like Cloudinary to host the images, but this further extends my application's dependencies and I would rather just use Firebase for storage.

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `prodImgUrl` must be publicly accessible so your hunch about access seems relevant. I recommend testing with a different image URL (that you know is public) to see if you can attribute this to FS or not.

Comment: @LauraT Just tested with a url from the Unsplash API and the image shows up. It must be something to do with the Firestore. I getDownloadUrl for the Firestore image and pass it to Stripe though, so seems a little odd. I have used completely open security rules for reads on the Firestore, so Stripe should have access. I will investigate/test further and update. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Further researching this issue, I have concluded that I am unable to obtain a raw url  to a document from Firestore (which can be obtained from services such as Usplash API) and therefore Stripe will not be able to access the image I have stored in Firestore. I think my only options are to use a CDN or hosting service (such as Cloudinary). It has been interesting exploring the possibilities with Firestore though.